# Laravel command re-create bills

Tags: php, laravel

I have code below in my console command, which runs by cronjob but it has 1 issue

```
public function handle()
{
    $now = Carbon::today();
    $invoices = Invoice::where('paid', true)->latest()->get();
    foreach($invoices as $invoice)
    {
        if($invoice->end->EqualTo($now) || $invoice->end->subDays(7)) {
            $inn = Invoice::create([
                'invoice_nu' => uniqid(),
                'school_id' => $invoice->school_id,
                'user_id' => $invoice->user_id,
                'start' => $invoice->end->addDay(1),
                'end' => $invoice->end->addMonth(1),
                'amount' => $invoice->amount,
                'paid' => false,
            ]);

            if($inn) {
                Log::info("Invoice Created Event Fire: ".$inn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### The issue

The issue is that this function creates new bills every day even for those who already has unpaid bills. (multiple)

#### Logic

1. I want to get `latest bills (invoices)` of all schools
2. Filter those who are marked as `paid`
3. Marked those who their `end` date is today
4. Create new bills for them.

> **So it'll be like:**
>
> If your last bill is paid, and your end date is today, I make you new bill.
>
> If your last bill is unpaid, I won't make you new bill regardless of end date.

#### Schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('invoice_nu')->unique();
        $table->uuid('school_id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->bigInteger('amount');
        $table->date('start');
        $table->date('end');
        $table->boolean('paid')->default(false);
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->string('receiptNo')->nullable();
        $table->string('byname')->nullable();
        $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Relations**

`School.php`

```
public function invoices() {
  return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
}
```

`Invoice.php`

```
public function school() {
  return $this->belongsTo(School::class);
}
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is, you are not checking for already added invoice for an ending invoice. and the if condition is always true because of `$invoice->end->subDays(7)` as you are not checking it with anything. it just outputs a date. i believe you are trying to check if the invoice end date is within the next 7 days. so change the condition and add another if to check for already added invoice or existing unpaid invoice.

```
if ($invoice->end->EqualTo($now) || $now->diffInDays($invoice->end) <= 7) {
    $exist = Invoice::where('school_id', $invoice->school_id)->where('paid', false)->first();
    if ($exist) {
        //do if you have to do anything if already exists
    } else {
        $inn = Invoice::create([
            'invoice_nu' => uniqid(),
            'school_id' => $invoice->school_id,
            'user_id' => $invoice->user_id,
            'start' => $invoice->end->addDay(1),
            'end' => $invoice->end->addMonth(1),
            'amount' => $invoice->amount,
            'paid' => false,
        ]);

        if ($inn) {
            Log::info("Invoice Created Event Fire: ".$inn);
        }
    }
}
```

this is just an example based on your logic. you can improve your logic to check for existing invoices maybe when you are fetching the invoices first time.

Comment: thank you, is it possible to explain this part `($now->diffInDays($invoice->end, false) > 0 && $now->diffInDays($invoice->end) <= 7)` so I can understand what you did as well?

Comment: this `if ($invoice->end->EqualTo($now) || $now->diffInDays($invoice->end) <= 7)` seem to be working please tell me if you think it might be something wrong with it

Comment: here i am just checking if invoice end is within the next 7 days..diffInDays returns difference between two dates in days..without the false argument it returns positive number for any case..like if we compare now with tomorrow or yesterday it returns 1for both the case..false argument returns positive 1 for tomorrow and negative 1 for yesterday..and yeah you can exclude this check..just day difference is enough in your case

Comment: please just change your code to my working code so i can accept it because that is the way works in my case. (wanna answer be match with question for others to see this later on)